# Вывод в Toast контента из 2х удалённых файлов

Tags: android

Всем привет, есть код вывода содержания файла в интернете. Мне нужно, чтобы в тоаст выводилось содержание из 2х файлов. вот полный код активити

```
package com.example.byfile;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.example.byfile.R;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     Button btnSend;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final Button btnSend = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
            btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(final View v)
                {
                    new Thread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                 final URL myURL = new URL("http://мой-сайт/1.txt");
                                    final URLConnection connection = myURL.openConnection();
                                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                                    final Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

                                    final URL myURL2 = new URL("http://мой-сайт/2.txt");
                                    final URLConnection connection2 = myURL2.openConnection();
                                    connection2.setDoInput(true);
                                    final Reader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection2.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                                try
                                {
                                    //буфер 1   
                                    final char [] buffer1 = new char[1024];
                                    final StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

                                    int readCount;
                                    do
                                    {
                                        readCount = reader.read(buffer1);
                                        message.append(buffer1);
                                    }
                                    while (readCount >= buffer1.length);

                                    //буфер 2
                                    final char [] buffer2 = new char[1024];
                                    final StringBuilder message2 = new StringBuilder();

                                    int readCount2;
                                    do
                                    {
                                        readCount2 = reader2.read(buffer2);
                                        message2.append(buffer2);
                                    }
                                    while (readCount2 >= buffer2.length);

                                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run()
                                        {

                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), message + message2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                                catch (final IOException ex)
                                {
                                    Log.d("IOException", ex.getMessage());
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    reader.close();
                                }
                            }
                            catch (final Exception ex)
                            {
                                Log.d("Some exception", ex.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();

                }
            });

}}
```

Comment: и в чем проблема то?
выводится только с одного файла, только со второго, ни с какого, программа вылетает или что вообще?

Comment: в этой задаче лучше использовать AsynkTask, у которого есть нормальный доступ к основному потоку перед и после исполнения

Comment: выводится только второй файл, а нужно оба. сможете написать пример с AsynkTaskом?

Comment: код работает как надо (протестил у себя с файлами с дропбокса).
может у тебя файл первый не в той кодировке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может вообще дело в этом:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), message + message2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

И надо заменить на:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), message.toString() + message2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```